# OpenGL "motion dragging" effect - Not clearing screen every frame

Tags: c, opengl, graphics

I have an OpenGL game that works fine, except I want to apply the "dragging" effect to moving objects: where you see their trails from their previous positions as they move.

What I tried was to clear the color buffer only every few frames instead of every frame, yet that doesn't work:[image] The trails don't get erased at all, even though I do call glClear every 50 frames or so.
[image] This image shows the extremely annoying flicker it has.

Can someone explain either why this happens in OpenGL and how to fix it or perhaps an alternate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for "motion blur + opengl".  This is a full-screen post processing effect.  Another way  of doing it would to be to store trails for each object in a dequeue, where you push the current position at one end and take it off the other, drawing an effect for each item in the queue (perhaps making the item more and more opaque as you go).

Otherwise without code it's very hard to know what you're doing.  I'm pretty sure just not clearing the colour buffer won't work!

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into using the glAccum buffer. Do you perhaps know how to enable it in SFML?

Comment: Sorry to say that SFML doesn't support it.  You can do it with post-processing and FBO's with appropriate shaders of course, but the old vanilla implementation won't work with this library.